# How to hide/not draw part of the model

Tags: c#, 3d, xna-4.0

I have an animated model that's spinning.

I want to hide/not draw any part of the model that's Y<0

what are the ways I can do it?

ideas:

1) draw a giant rectangular box right below y=0

2) tweak the camera matrix so that y<0 is outside of clipping plane (but i have no idea how)

can someone point me into the right direction? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A purely mathematical approach:

- Don't draw the polygons whose y's are all less than 0.
- Draw the polygons whose y's are all greater than or equal to 0.
- Clip the rest of the polygons with the y=0 plane and draw them.

If the polygons making up the model are triangles, clipping them is pretty trivial. You need to clip the two sides intersecting with the y=0 plane and replace the original vertices whose y's are less than 0 with the intersection points of those two sides with the clipping plane.

Use the line equations:
(x-x1) = (x2-x1)*(y-y1)/(y2-y1)
(z-z1) = (z2-z1)*(y-y1)/(y2-y1)

where 1 and 2 are the vertices of the side being clipped by the y=0 plane. Substitute their coordinates (x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) and y=0 into the equations to get x and z of the intersection point. Use this point's coordinates instead of vertex 1's or 2's (whichever has y < 0).

If the polygons are texture-mapped, you'll need to recalculate the texture coordinates for the vertices that you got from the clipping. You do that in the same fashion.

Comment: i'm a little bit confuse here, so I have to clip the model's vertices?
if so, what function(s) will i be calling to clip them?

Comment: @Krispy: you may need to implement them yourself if there's nothing suitable in the libraries used.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to introduce [MSDN Bounding Frustum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingfrustum.aspx)

Here is a good tutorial from [Nic's GameDev Site](http://nfostergames.com/Lessons/SimpleViewCulling.htm).